# 3D point cloud edge or wrap detection

Tags: python, edge-detection, point-clouds

after a segmentation step, I would like to detect the edge of every point cloud object in my scene. So does anyone know some alternative to do this in python?

Comment: do you have any code? alternative to what?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I know there is a ConvexHulll function in scipy but I didn't test if it can do what I am looking for.

Comment: ConvexHull will give you all the points/vertices on the boundary of a given point cloud. Its difficult to comment on your question fully without you posting any relavent code.

Comment: What do you call an edge ? Show us samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I use [lasboundary](https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools/raw/master/bin/lasboundary.exe) to get the cancave hull so I got the edge of my sets. We only shoul specify alpha to get convex or concave hull. Here is a sample of code with python:

```
import os
os.system('lasboundary -i mysets.txt -o myedge.txt -concavity 0.05')
```

Result is written in myedge.txt.